# Importing methods from built-in class for use in custom class - Python

Tags: python, string, class, methods

I created a class with extended methods for the built-in 'str' class, but I want the user to be able to use those normal built-in methods for strings as well as my extra methods. How would I do this without having to manually code each method already in the 'str' class?

```
class StringMethods:
    """
    StringMethods class:
    
    A class similar to the built in python str class
    but with extended methods for string analysis, password checking etc.
    """
    
    def __init__(self, string: str) -> None:
        
        self.string = string
    
    
    def contains(self, char: str) -> bool:
        
        if char in self.string:
            return True
        return False
    
    
    def containsany(self, chars: str | list | tuple | set) -> bool:
        
        for char in chars:
            if char in self.string:
                return True
        return False
    
    
    def hasdigit(self) -> bool: return self.containsany("0123456789")
    def haslower(self) -> bool: return self.containsany("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz")
    def hasupper(self) -> bool: return self.containsany("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ")
    def haswhitespace(self) -> bool: return self.contains(" ")


# I want the user to be able to do the following:
my_string = StringMethods("string123")
print(my_string.hasdigit()) # custom method
print(my_string.upper())    # built-in str method
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a class that inherits from `str()` and is extended with your functions.

```
class StringMethod(str):
"""
StringMethods class:

A class inheriting from the built in python str class
but with extended methods for string analysis, password checking etc.
"""

def contains(self, char: str) -> bool:
    
    return self.__contains__(char)


def containsany(self, chars: str | list | tuple | set) -> bool:
    
    for char in chars:
        if char in self.__str__():
            return True
    return False


def hasdigit(self) -> bool: return self.containsany("0123456789")
def haslower(self) -> bool: return self.containsany("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz")
def hasupper(self) -> bool: return self.containsany("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ")
def haswhitespace(self) -> bool: return self.contains(" ")
```

Notice that I dropped the `__init__()` method as `str()` provides that already. With this class you can use any builtin string methods plus your own special methods.

Comment: `char in self` is sufficient; no need to call the `__str__` method explicitly.

Comment: In fact, `StringMethods.contains` is really just an alias for `str.__contains__`.

Comment: Thanks for this @user99999, one last question - Can you think of a better name for my class?

Comment: @darragh naming is your responsibility. As a side note you can override the builtin str() class in your program with this `str = StringMethod()`. Then any calls as in `str('mypassword').hasdigit()` will work for you as will `str('mypassword').upper()`. HTH

Comment: Check your spelling. You misspelled `StringMethod()` as `StringMethods()`.

Comment: When I did this, it said "NameError: name 'StringMethods' is not defined"

Comment: It's spelled StringMethods() in my program, see above

Comment: Edit your post to show that code.

Comment: It has been like that, it's your code that's different

Comment: @user99999 That redefines `str` to be an *instance* of `StringMethod`, not the class `StringMethod` itself. You meant `str = StringMethod`. Regardless, that's probably a bad idea. Keep separate classes separate.